# Wifi Card not working Ubuntu 22.04 on Razer Blade 15 2022

Tags: drivers, wireless, laptop, 22.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Razer Blade 15" 2022 model.
Ubuntu is Dual Booted alongside Windows on a separate SSD.
The system is not able to detect my wifi card.

From the razer website, I found that my wifi spec is `Wi-Fi 6E, IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac/ax/az`

I have tried:

- disabling the "Turn off device to save power" setting on windows device manager for the wifi card.
- Installing openrazer
- Running lspci which does not show any network adapters

[image]

Comment: lspci shows a network adapter on 00:14.3. Can you add the output of lspci -s 00:14.3 -knn?

Comment: @EmreTalha I managed to fix the problem by updating to the latest Kernel.

Comment: For me upgrading the kernel also worked. For reference, I used the latest stable kernel that was available at the time, which is 5.19.3-051903-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to upgrade the Kernel to the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the kernel worked for me as well.

If you don't have WiFi access on your Ubuntu machine due to the kernel not recognizing the WiFi card, you can still install a newer kernel or necessary drivers manually using another computer with internet access. Here's a step-by-step process:

1. **Using Another Computer with Internet Access**:

   a. Visit the Ubuntu kernel download webpage: [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/).

   b. Choose a kernel version you want to download. If you're uncertain, choose one of the newer versions but ensure it's marked as stable.

   c. Download the following `.deb` packages based on your system architecture:

   - For 64-bit systems:

     - `linux-headers-XXXXX_all.deb`
     - `linux-headers-XXXXX-generic-XXXXX_amd64.deb`
     - `linux-image-XXXXX-generic-XXXXX_amd64.deb`
     - (Optionally) `linux-modules-XXXXX-generic-XXXXX_amd64.deb` (if available)
   - For 32-bit systems:

     - `linux-headers-XXXXX_all.deb`
     - `linux-headers-XXXXX-generic-XXXXX_i386.deb`
     - `linux-image-XXXXX-generic-XXXXX_i386.deb`
     - (Optionally) `linux-modules-XXXXX-generic-XXXXX_i386.deb` (if available)

   d. Once you've downloaded these files, transfer them to a USB stick or any portable storage.
2. **Installing the Kernel on Your Ubuntu Machine**:

   a. Plug in the USB stick to your Ubuntu machine.

   b. Copy the `.deb` files to a directory on your computer. Let's say you copied them to a directory called `kernel-update` in your home directory.

   c. Open a terminal and navigate to that directory:

   ```bash
   cd ~/kernel-update
   ```

   d. Install the kernel using the `dpkg` command:

   ```bash
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

   e. Once installed, update the GRUB bootloader and reboot:

   ```bash
   sudo update-grub
   sudo reboot
   ```
3. **Selecting the New Kernel**:

   Upon reboot, your system should default to the latest kernel. If not, at the GRUB menu during boot, go to "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and select the kernel you just installed.

After booting into the new kernel, check if your WiFi is working. If it's not, you might still need WiFi drivers, which would involve a similar process: downloading on a different computer, transferring them via USB, and then installing on your Ubuntu machine.

Remember: installing new kernels can sometimes introduce other issues. Always make sure you have a backup of your important data, and keep the previous kernel version intact so you can boot into it if necessary.